# What is the difference in the two swap rate as seen in this link?

Tags: interest-rate-swap

https://www.chathamfinancial.com/technology/us-market-rates

there are two swap rate, Swaps – Semi-bond and Swaps – Monthly Money. What is the difference between the two rate?

Comment: It's as if though Chatham Financial intentionally makes these things look more complicated than they are :) this is answered in my answer to the linked question.  [What is the relation between the USD Swaps Rates and US treasuries?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59176/what-is-the-relation-between-the-usd-swaps-rates-and-us-treasuries)

Comment: @DimitriVulis Thanks for the comment, so, say I enter a 1 year Semi-Bond swap with size 100 USD, do I pay 0.1 USD every half year while the Bank pays me 100*3month LIBOR RATE/4 every quarter? Assmue swap rate is 0.2%

Comment: Yes, this sounds right.

Answer (score 1):

### Semi-Bond

These are based on an OTC swap contract in which a party pays the fixed rate semi-annually on a 30/360 basis, versus receiving 3-month LIBOR quarterly on an Actual/360 basis.

### Monthly Money

Monthly money swap rates are commonly used by real estate and corporate borrowers to hedge exposure to floating-rate 1-month LIBOR debt. The contractual basis is paying a fixed rate monthly on an Actual/360 basis, versus receiving 1-month LIBOR monthly on an Actual/360 basis, without amortization.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, so, say I enter a 1 year Semi-Bond swap with size 100 USD, do I pay 0.1 USD every half year while the Bank pays me 100*3month LIBOR RATE/4 every quarter? Assume swap rate is 0.2%

Comment: To be precise, the bank will pay you 3M Libor on an Actual/360 basis very quarter.  You will need to count the actual days in the quarter.